# Ordering dictionary ascending and descending both

Tags: c#, .net

I have a

```
Dictionary<int, float>frequencies
```

Of numbers (int) and their frequencies. 
I need to order them by frequency descending, so i put

```
frequencies.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value).
```

The problem is that it orders the keys ascending. That is correct but I only need the first n keys to be ordered descending and the others ascending.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Example:
Now i have:

- frequencies: 7  7  6  5 4 4  4  4  4  4 3 3 3
- numbers:     7 36 26 35 1 5 22 23 31 34 2 4 6

My dictionary needs to look like this:

- frequencies:  7 7  6  5  4 and then like the upper one.
- numbers:     36 7 26 35  3

Just the first five numbers need to be descending and the others ascending.

Comment: You shouldn´t rely on the elements within a dictionary beeing ordered in *any* way as a dictionary is a map computed on **hashcodes**. Having said the order of the elements is completely arbitrary (whilst deterministic). Do you really want your dictionary to be ordered (which is impossible), or just *use* its values in an ordered fashion?

Comment: It doesn't help your question that you swapped the order of keys and values in your text, nor that you haven't provided a [mcve] that answerers can copy-paste. Anyway, you're looking for `dict.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value).ThenByDescending(kvp => kvp.Key)`, see duplicate and [this Ideone](http://ideone.com/OjYVHE).

Comment: in need the first five to be .ThenByDescending(kvp => kvp.Key) and all the other .ThenByAscending(kvp => kvp.Key)

Comment: Does https://dotnetfiddle.net/kHV2T2 work? (It should if by 36 7 26 35 3 you mean 36 7 26 35 34)

Comment: My answer uses a List - but you could use this if you really need it in a Dictionary - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18615/OrderedDictionary-T-A-generic-implementation-of-IO .